# How to recover files from crashed Windows computer with Ubuntu

Tags: installation

My HP pavillion crashed and I read that I could create a boot disk in order to retrieve my files by using Ubuntu.

The Ubuntu-13.10 is in my download folder on a different laptop.  When I select it, I'm asked to use ISO viewer or Windows explorer to open.

I am trying to get the file onto a DVD so I can put it in the crashed HP laptop.  Can someone assist.  I have the file open using Cyberlink ISO Viewer  Do I select WUBI.EXE to download to this laptop then put it on the DVD?

Answer (score 0):

No, instead you use a different program to extract the ISO image to bootable media, such as a USB flashdrive, following these instructions direct from Ubuntu [click this link for the instructions in more detail](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows).

> Download the Pen Drive Linux's USB Installer.
>   Pick **Ubuntu Desktop Edition** from the dropdown list.
>   Click 'Browse' and open your downloaded ISO file.
>   Choose the USB drive and click 'Create'.

Once created, then safely remove the USB drive from your Windows machine, put it in the sick Pavilion and reboot. There's a list of function keys which comes up on the screen early in the reboot process; one will give you a list of boot devices ( F6, maybe? It varies). Press that during reboot and then choose the USB flash drive, and Ubuntu will launch.

Once Ubuntu is up, you can use the [Nautilus File Manager](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Nautilus/Screenshots) to copy files from your hard drive to a flash drive (this one or another one) or to an externally connected hard drive. Nautilus is very much like Windows File Explorer.

Comment: So that I understand this, The files that I just downloaded onto my laptop, I now need to move them to USB

Comment: Copy them, yes, or to an external hard drive, your choice. It's also possible to copy them to a series of DVD-R discs if your Pavilion has a DVD writer, or to a series of CD-R discs if your Pavilion has a CD writer, but a flashdrive or external hard drive are easier to copy to.

Comment: ok.  I selected f9 and got the menu.  Selected my USB,and the installation menu populated to try or install.  should I select "try".

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.  I used the Try version and was able to move my files to my external drive.  Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Then, click on the checkmark-on-circle at left to show the answer worked for you, which will help the next person with your problem find it easier.